# Is there a way to have an <xsl:element> tag render *only* if its content template has either children or raw data i.e. complex or simple types?

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, transform, xslt-1.0

Folks,

**Is there a way to have an  tag render *only* if its content template has either children or raw data i.e. complex or simple types?**

Assume my XML Data looks like this:

### Data

```
<Root>
   <Data>stringdata</Data>
</Root>
```

and my XSLT looks like this:

### XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
  <xsl:element name="Empty">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Data = 'stringdata'">
        <xsl:value-of select="Data"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

When the  does NOT contain "stringdata", then an empty element named  will be displayed.  Short of wrapping  with a choose or an if statement, or designing a second transform to match on only those elements produced in the first transform that have data within them, how can I prevent  from being produced?

Comment: Provide some examples of different input data and desired output result.

Comment: I think you have listed the options available. If you want something done conditionally, using xsl:if doesn't seem a great hardship.

Comment: @MichaelKay

Using xsl:if isn't a "hardship" it is simply insufficient for the need.  I do not know if <Empty> will contain data or elements until the transform is applied; therefore, using an xsl:if would require that I understand the conditions that would cause <Empty> to have no simple content (string, numbers, etc) and no child elements that have simple content.

The need is to suppress the production of an xsl:element if that element has no child elements i.e. complex or simple content.  That seems like it would be most properly done on the xsl:element or the xsl:stylesheet

Comment: @penartur

Using this XSLT:

<xsl:template match="/Root">
  <xsl:element name="Empty">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Data = 'stringdata'">
        <xsl:value-of select="Data"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

I want this data:

<Root>
   <Data>stringdata</Data>
</Root>

to produce:

[nothing]

and this data:

<Root>
   <Data>NOTstringdata</Data>
</Root>

to produce:

<Empty>NOTstringdata</Empty>

I want <Empty> to be not produced when it has no content.

Comment: @jason.t.knight Please provide the examples of input XMLs and desired output XMLs so that one could understand what do you want to achieve just by looking at these XMLs.

Comment: @penartur

I want xslt to take the following XML data:

<Root>
   <Data>stringdata</Data>
</Root>

and know to produce:

<Empty>stringdata</Empty>

yet when the input XML is:

<Root>
   <Data>NOTstringdata</Data>
</Root>

I want it to produce:

[nothing]

When given the "NOTstringdata" option, the current XSLT will produce:

<Empty />

Without using an xsl:choose, xsl:if, or without running the ouput of that XSLT through another XSLT, how can that <Empty /> tag be suppressed or removed simply because it has no complex or simple content?

Comment: Could you update the original question instead of putting it in the comments, it is very difficult to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you could do this simply by checking the condition in the template

```
<xsl:template match="Root[Data = 'stringdata']">
   <!-- Output Empty Element -->
<xsl:template>
```

You would also need a second template to match **Root** elements that don't match and do nothing

```
<xsl:template match="Root" />
```

Note that the more specific template will always take priority.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="Root[Data = 'stringdata']">
      <Empty>
         <xsl:value-of select="Data"/>
      </Empty>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Root"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following it output

```
<Empty>stringdata</Empty>
```

Change the text to anything else, and nothing is output.

Comment: Your solution will use foreknowledge of the data to *prevent* the element from being produced.  I am looking for a method that will cause an xsl:element to get "filtered" or have it's creation suppressed simply because that xsl:element has no children or data within it.

Comment: @jason.t.knight: Of course when one writes a transformation they must know the structure of the data. Otherwise it becomes like those monkeys, that given a typewriter each, will write all Shakespeare's works if they work just for 200 years. TimC has given you the best, truly XSLT solution. Another solution is two-pass processing, where the second pass deletes any empty elements created by the first pass.

Comment: I think you have finally address my question, which is that XSLT doesn't have the "single-pass" ability to first produce an element, then have that element filter itself out if it has no children (simple content or complex content).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your above comment where you said:

> I want this data: `<Root> <Data>stringdata</Data> </Root>` to produce:
>   [nothing] and this data: `<Root> <Data>NOTstringdata</Data> </Root>` to
>   produce: `<Empty>NOTstringdata</Empty>` I want `<Empty>` to be not
>   produced when it has no content.

I believe this achieves what you want:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(Data='')">
        <!-- Data is not null, now we look to see what sort of Data is there-->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Data = 'stringdata'">
                <!--nothing-->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!--ie. have notstringdata-->
                <xsl:element name="Empty">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Data"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

      </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--no Data, so no element created, or you could do something specific for this scenario-->
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Though, I must say, that using the name "Empty" for the element name makes things a bit confusing given the way you expect to use it.

Comment: Your solution will use foreknowledge of the data to *prevent* the element from being produced.  I am looking for a method that will cause an xsl:element to get "filtered" or have it's creation suppressed simply because that xsl:element has no children or data within it.